# How to point default virtual host in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, linode

I recently purchased linode hosting where i did successfully hosted a website. And its opening by domain-name.com and also when i enter server IP it opens default /var/www/domain-name.com/public_html

Now i want to host another site in it and created another virtual host with domain-name-2.com and enabled that and did reload my apache server.

Now when i enter again the server IP in browser like http://11.22.33.44/ it shows the first website (/var/www/domain-name.com/public_html) i hosted by default.

But i want to point some other folder so that when i hit http://11.22.33.44 it will show that folder's index.html not /var/www/domain-name.com/public_html

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, you want

http://11.22.33.44/ -> /var/www/domain-name.com/some_other_folder

http://domain-name.com/ -> /var/www/domain-name.com/public_html

Am I correct?

If that is the case, go to /etc/apach2/site-available

in 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-name.com/some_other_folder
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Create a new file called "domain-name.com.conf" in the same folder

Write the following into the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-name.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

To enable virtual host, type into terminal:

```
$ sudo a2ensite domain-name.com
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, anyway, In 000-default.conf its already pointed to DocumentRoot /var/www/html and in html folder there is a index.html. So as per this when i hit http://11.22.33.44/ it should open /var/www/html/index.html but it's opening /var/www/domain-name.com/public_html

Answer (score 0):

Basically `000-default.conf` wasn't working as it was disabled.

enable it by following command -

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
```

I was wondering why it opening my 000-domain-name.com.conf it's because may be as default conf has been disabled so apache search for other conf file alphabetically as act that as default conf.

Also if you want to disable default conf

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Both above command require apache to be restarted by following command -

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```